# Best way to find a "version" of the C# shared project in a submodule

Tags: c#, git, version, project, share

I create a C# .net project, using another shared project in it.
Both are in GitHub, but different repos and might be from different owners.
The shared project is added as a git submodule.

Is there anyway to get "the version" of that shared project, in my main project?
The shared has no "version", that's why I write it "like this".
But at least the last changed date in the shared project?

I might somehow find the commit id in the shared repo, but that's not so useful for users.
I want the users should be able see "how new" the shared project is used.

Or a nice way to (automatically?) update a proper version number in the shared proj.
Or is the only way to use a `public static Version` and manually update ut when committing to the shared repo?

Better ideas?

Comment: Give it a version via the AssemblyVersionAttribute normally located in the AssemblyInfo.cs and update that in a build process of yours?

Comment: Thanks @Ralf I see it ofc in the AssemblyInfo.cs, but that's in the "main" project, the shared project (*.shproj) is what I'm looking for... shproj has no such info, it is "dumb" with only holds the cs-files, which may be used by the main projects (*.csproj) if added them as Reference.

Comment: Ah you meant that thing as shared not any library. In that case its just a bunch of linked files at the end no individual assembly with a version. Hmh in that case you need to role your own solution presumably. Does it need to be a shared that way and can't be a "real" assembly? Feels somewhat weird to version a bunch of source files and not a compiled thing and even give a user a version for that.

Comment: I agree... But like this case: there are two projects (by different creators) using the same submodule, and integrated projects (long story...) they can't have the same features in their own version (actually commit-ids) of the submodule. So I want it to be possible to compare "versions", gladly if I find info in the submodule-commit, but a version-ish number. I know, I sound strange now... 